# Bitbucket cloud integration with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have configured Bitbucket to push code to the URL:  https://My-Jenkins-in-aws/bitbucket-hook/

[and I see 200 as the status code for each commit I do to this repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYwcR.png)  which may mean webhook is doing its job.

But in Jenkins, I see Authentication failed as below

Started on Jun 23, 2022, 6:51:28 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 800c0ea1gbb05df9967b888367341d87279367d4 (refs/remotes/origin/dev)
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified

> git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
> git ls-remote -h -- https://user@bitbucket.org/path/to.git # timeout=10
> FATAL: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h -- https://user@bitbucket.org/path/to.git" returned status code 128:
> stdout:
> stderr: remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
> remote: See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
> remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
> remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/path/to.git/'

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h -- https://UserName@bitbucket.org/path/to/.git" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
remote: See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/path/to.git/'

If I build it manually from Jenkins, it clones the code and builds normally without an authentication error.

Let me know if you have any more questions about this.

Appreciate any help :)

Thanks,
Ravikiran HM

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I see that your problem is that you're trying to use a normal Bitbucket password which are not allowed here. The error log points at https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/, so go there and you will find an option to create an app password for your pipeline. Once you have the app password, replace all instances of your normal password with the app password and everything should start working. Note that the app password should be kept safe since it can be used as an alternative to your normal password.

Also note that the app password does not expire and gives restrictive access. If anything is unclear, read through the other link shown in the error message: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231

Comment: Yeah I agree.. I have done this... I'm passing the app password along with Git repository URL as https://UserName:appPassword@bitbucket.org/path/to/.git" , while building manually it's fine , when building on code committ I see this error in Bit Bucket hook log... Still no luck..